# Vba Application for data entry not working

Tags: excel, vba

I built an application in VBA to enter data in excel tables easier. I get stuck with the following line:

```
'''''Add data
Dim lr As Integer
' (here i get runtime error 424 Object required) What should i do?
lr = Appliction.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))


sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = "lr"
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.Txt_product.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = Me.Txt_vanzare.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = Me.Txt_achizitie.Value

'''''Clear Boxes
Me.Txt_product.Value = ""
Me.Txt_vanzare.Value = ""
Me.Txt_achizitie.Value = ""

MsgBox "Produsul a fost adaugat in Product Master", vbInformation
```

The rest of it work just fine. Can someone explain me what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is sh? Is it set to something?

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `Appliction.WorksheetFunction` instead of `Appliction.WorksheetFunction`. No `Appliction` object exists...